# How to calculate/set font line margin itextPDF

Tags: java, itext, footer

I am implementing PdfPageEventHelper event and footer stuff is as below:

```
             ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(String.format(" %d ", 
            writer.getPageNumber()),footerFont), 
            document.right() - 2 , document.bottom() - 20, 0);
```

Now, i have 3 lines which needs to be added into footer but i don't find a best to set its vertical margin. (Each 3 LINES has different font SIZE).
what should keep for - document.bottom() - XXX ??

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two lines is the `leading`. You can pick your own leading, but it is custom to use 1.5 times the font size. You are drawing line by line yourself, using different font sizes, so you'll have to adjust the Y value based on that font size. Note that `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` uses the Y value as the baseline of the text you're adding, so if you have some text with font size of 12pt, you'd need to take into account a leading of 18pt. If you have a font size 8pt, you make sure you have 12pt.

That's the easy solution: based on "convention". If you really want to know how much horizontal space some *specific* takes, you need to calculate the ascender and the descender, as is done in [figure 3.7 of my book](http://www.flickr.com/photos/itextinaction/4330322144/). You'll find the code [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=61). If `bf` is your font (a `BaseFont` object), `text` is your text (a `String`) and `size` is your font size (a `float`), then the height of your text is equal to `height`:

```
float aboveBaseline = bf.getAscentPoint(text, size);
float underBaseline = bf.getDescentPoint(text, size);
float height = aboveBaseline - underBaseline;
```

When `y` is the Y-coordinate used in `showTextAligned()` make sure you keep the space between `y + aboveBaseline` and `y + underBaseline` free. This is the *accurate* solution.

Note that `document.bottom() - 20` looks somewhat strange. I would expect `document.bottom() + 20` as the Y-axis of the PDF coordinate system points upwards, not downwards.